# Passport JWT Strategy not getting called

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, express-jwt

I am trying to authorise my JWT token with passport middleware but the strategy callback function is not getting called.

In my `app.js` file, I am specifying for my `/users` routes to use the middleware like so:

```
app.use('/users', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), users);
```

I then have a seperate file `./passport.js` (which I have required at the top of my `app.js`) where I specify my passport strategy:

```
passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey   : 'jwt_secret_key'
    },
    function (jwtPayload, cb) {
        console.log('jwtPayload', jwtPayload)
    }
));
```

I can't get the console log to run though.

I am using postman to test this and have selected `Bearer Token` from the authorization options. I can see that this is adding a header to my request.

When I log my request object in my node app, I can see it looks like this:

```
headers: { 
    authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YWM0YWI2ZTk1MWJiMjE1M2NhMjc0OWUiLCJmaXJzdF9uYW1lIjoiQW5kcmV3IiwibGFzdF9uYW1lIjoiTWNDYWxsdW0iLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFtY2NhbGx1bTg5QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTUyMjg0NzEyNSwiZXhwIjoxNTIyODUwNzI1fQ.WH12GJHMGrGsiJNIwUG2Dx_a9cZKjw7_SW8FYlEvLmk',
    accept: '*/*',
    host: 'localhost:3037',
},
```

So the middleware should detect the bearer token and call the middleware?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So... presuming somewhere you've got the line `app.use(passport.initialize())`?

Comment: No I don't. I have just got it working. Looks like my `secretOrKey` in my strategy didn't match my `secretOrKey` where I create my token. Not sure why it was failing silently but looks like that was causing the issue as it is working now.

Comment: hmm I was always under the impression `passport.initialize()` was a requirement when using Express w/ Passport.

Comment: Do you have an example of how / where it's used? Maybe I'm missing something without realising

Comment: It's still in the [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/), see the `middleware` section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out my `secretOrKey` didn't match my `secretOrKey` where I was creating my JWT token.

I.E passport strategy needs to have the same `secretOrKey`

```
passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey   : 'jwt_secret_key'
    },
    function (jwtPayload, cb) {
        console.log('jwtPayload', jwtPayload)
    }
));
```

as

```
const secretOrKey = 'jwt_secret_key'
const token = jwt.sign(payload, secretOrKey, { expiresIn });
```

Comment: This happened to me and I found out  it was the secret key. Check that your secret key are the same in signing and verification.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue I was facing and I found this on github.
https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt/issues/153

you have to change `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()` to `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')` or `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT')`

Comment: Can you extend your answer, why this fixes the issue?

Comment: For me it worked by using `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("Bearer")` which I think could also be used as `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()`. So the argument basically tells about auth scheme and in this case of OP it should be Bearer instead of JWT

Comment: Thanks this is working fine now. ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the documentation for NestJS, something seems to have been left out. Kindly make sure that you are also passing the secret during signing. I have mine in my .env file, thus the code snippet below:

```
this.jwtService.sign(payload, {secret: `${process.env.SECRET}`}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my answer. I spent an hour figuring out this issue, turns out it's my fault in configuring Postman.

So I'm a newbie in node-express, and I made 1 production rest api app already but in this second project, I couldn't figure out the issue.

I'm using constants through `config.js` so the keys weren't my problem for sure.

So going back to Postman, I checked my old project's postman collection. I checked the `Header` and it just had single `Authorization` key. And the value is something like: `Bearer xxxxx`. And when I went back to my current project, I wondered why my `Authorization` key has a value of `Bearer Bearer xxx`...

I figured that I must delete the `Bearer` thing when using the `AUTHORIZATION OAUTH2.0` of Postman. Voila! Work great! I must've forgotten this proper configuration in Postman.

Here's how I setup my **JwtStrategy**:

```
// JSON WEB TOKENS STRATEGY
passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: config.JWT_SECRET
}, async (payload, done) => {

  console.log("Find by pk, JWT strategy:", payload.sub)

  db.User.findByPk(payload.sub, {
```